# How to change title and icon for a jasper reports PDF with Spring Boot 2+?

Tags: java, spring

I'm generating a report with **JasperReports** in a new tab in PDF format, using **Spring Boot 2.0.1**, everything is working as expected.

But I want change the title and icon of the pages that reports are generated, because it is getting the default icon of spring, and the title is getting the controller mapping.

**Image of what is going on:**

[image: A sample!]

**OBS.:** as you know, Spring losts the integration with JasperReports, so in my controller I'm returning a byte[] instead of a modelAndView.

### Code:

```
@PostMapping("/filtro")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> gerarRelatorio(Principal principal, IncidenciaLista conteudo) throws Exception{

    UsuarioSistema us = (UsuarioSistema) ((Authentication) principal).getPrincipal();

    byte[] relatorio = relatorioService.gerarRelatorioFiltrado(us.getUsuario().getEmpresa().getNome(), conteudo.getNomeProjeto(), conteudo.getLista());

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
            .body(relatorio);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an `favicon.ico` image to `src/main/resources/favicon.ico`

The image should meet the following criteria,

`name - favicon.ico
size - 32x32 or 16x16 pixels
Color - 265`

Comment: Hey thanks, it works. I miss this too: "/favicon.ico").permitAll() in security class!

Comment: Now I have to see how change the title...I changed the URL on controller, but is a bad solution for this...